# Create signed PDF (PAdES) with node.js

Tags: node.js, pdf, sign, pades

I'm generating PDFs in node.js.

My Goal is to digitally sign this PDFs before going on, to make sure any manipulation within these files is visible and also to gain some trust because the user is able to see these certificate in his pdf app.

I don't want to use another service, but haven't been able to find a library which is able to sign PDFs. Any hints?

Comment: Did you find out a solution?

Comment: nope, ended up using php :/

Answer (score 2):

I am currently working on the [node-signpdf npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-signpdf) (at the moment of writing this answer the version is 0.0.3). A readable snippet of PDF generation **and signing** can be seen [in the test code](https://github.com/vbuch/node-signpdf/blob/master/src/signpdf.test.js).

I also gave [the same answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51821079/2528232).